# strong word with regex

Tags: php, regex

I have this regex:

```
<?PHP
$test = 'this is a #test';
$regex = "#(\#.)#i";
$test = preg_replace($regex, '<strong>$1</strong>', $test);
echo $test;
?>
```

and I want the word after # to be in strong, but I only have #t in strong, does anybody have a suggestion?
thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `+` to match any one or more number literals. Use `*`, if you want to include `0` occurrence of literals after `#`.

```
   $regex = "#(\#.+)#i";
```

Please refer [**PHP Regex Repetition**](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.repetition.php) documentation for details.

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion would be something like this -

```
$regex = "/#(\w+)/i";
```

The `\w` means any [word character](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php). I'm also using the `+` [quantifier](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.repetition.php) which indicates that we must match at least one word character after the hash sign. I'm assuming we don't want just the hash sign to be `<strong>`   I also removed the hash sign (#) from the capture group as I'm not too sure you want that character to remain after you wrap it with `<strong>`.

One final note I'll leave you with is that if you find yourself using your [delimiter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) within your regular expression, you might want to consider changing it to something that you wouldn't use normally. In your case you had to escape the hash sign but in my example, I've changed the delimiter to slashes. It makes it a little bit easier to read as well :)

Comment: Note the change to `/` as regex delimiter in this answer. It is good practice that, if you are going to be having some symbol in your regex (like `#` in this case) to not use that as the regex delimiter, to make you code intent much clearer.

Comment: @mik - very true. I've just added that to my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?PHP
$test = 'this is a #test';
$regex = "#(\#.*)#i";
$test = preg_replace($regex, '<strong>$1</strong>', $test);
echo $test;
?>
```

The problem is . matches as single character only.

Comment: Your method will work even on a single `#` which is not the wanted result, I guess.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the amount of symbols to be saved:

```
$regex = "#(\#.{4})#i";
```

Comment: I can think of a few words with more than 4 characters :)